# Losing state while attaching firebase listener onto React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

So I am building a real time chat app with React hooks and Firebase listener, but I'm having issues with accessing the state of "messages" variable inside the listener. What I am assuming is that I should be able to access the "messages" variable inside the listener method. However, when the listener gets executed, it overwrites the state and I lose previous messages: when I try to console.log messages, it logs an empty array. Am I using the useState hooks correctly?

Chatroom.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { timeSince } from '../utils/utils.js'
import { db } from '../utils/firebase'

import './Chatroom.css'

const Chatroom = ({ match }) => {
  const feedID = match.params.id
  const messageSorter = new Date().getTime() * -1

  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true)
  const [messagesBackLength, setMessagesBackLength] = useState(0)
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    getMessages()
    firebaseListenToComments(feedID)
  }, [])

  const getMessages = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(
      `https://us-central1-DATABASE-dev.cloudfunctions.net/feed_api/${feedID}/messages?paginateKey=${messageSorter}`
    )

    const sortedMessages = res.data.data.messages.sort(
      (a, b) => b.sorter - a.sorter
    )

    setMessagesBackLength(res.data.data.messages.length)

    setMessages(sortedMessages)
  }

  const firebaseListenToComments = id => {
    let messagesRef = db.ref(`/social_feed_messages/${id}`)
    let startDate = new Date().getTime()

    messagesRef
      .orderByChild('creaionTime')
      .startAt(startDate)
      .limitToFirst(1)
      .on('child_added', data => {
        let newMessage = data.val()

        setMessages([newMessage, ...messages])
      })
  }

  const getOlderMessages = async () => {
    const paginateKey = (messages[messages.length - 1].sorter + 1).toString()

    const res = await axios.get(
      `https://us-central1-DATABASE-dev.cloudfunctions.net/feed_api/${feedID}/messages?paginateKey=${paginateKey}`
    )

    const olderMessages = res.data.data.messages.sort((a, b) => {
      return b.sorter - a.sorter
    })

    if (olderMessages.length < messagesBackLength) {
      setHasMore(false)
    }

    setMessages([...messages, ...olderMessages])
  }

  const postMessage = async e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    try {
      const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100).toString()
      const composerName = 'Tester name ' + randomNumber
      const creationTime = new Date().getTime()
      const sorter = creationTime * -1
      const formData = { message, composerName, creationTime, sorter }

      const res = await axios.post(
        `https://us-central1-DATABASE-dev.cloudfunctions.net/feed_api/${feedID}/messages`,
        formData
      )

      if (res.data.code === 'SUCCESS') {
        setMessages([formData, ...messages])

        setMessage('')
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message)
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <section className="main-comments">
        <div className="main-comments-top">
          <div className="main-comments-go-back">
            <Link to="/" className="go-back-btn">
              <div className="go-back">
                <i className="fas fa-chevron-circle-left fa-2x"></i>
              </div>
            </Link>

            <div className="main-comments-sender-info">
              <p className="post-fromto-info my-1 comments-sender-info">
                Comments
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="comment-form">
            <form className="comment-send-form" onSubmit={postMessage}>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="text"
                value={message}
                placeholder="Say something..."
                className="comment-form-input"
                onChange={e => setMessage(e.target.value)}
              />

              <Button
                className="msg-send-button"
                type="submit"
                disabled={message.length === 0}
              >
                <span>Post</span>
              </Button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="comments">
          <div className="comments-area">
            {messages
              .sort((a, b) => {
                return a.sorter - b.sorter
              })
              .map(msg => (
                <div className="com-each-comment" key={msg.creationTime}>
                  <div className="user-and-comment">
                    <p className="username-display">
                      <span>{msg.composerName}</span>
                    </p>
                    <p className="com-text-comment">{msg.message}</p>
                  </div>

                  <div className="comment-footer">
                    <small className="comment-timestamp">
                      {timeSince(msg.creationTime)}
                    </small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
          </div>

          <div className="comments-load-more">
            {hasMore && (
              <button className="load-more-button" onClick={getOlderMessages}>
                Load more
              </button>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  )
}

export default Chatroom
```

utils/firebase.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/database'

const config = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APP_ID,
}

firebase.initializeApp(config)

export const db = firebase.database()
```

Comment: It looks like you have a typo in `.orderByChild('creaionTime')`. There's a `t` missing in `creation` there.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen Thank you for catching that! Unfortunately, fixing that doesn't still lead me to the expected behaviour...I don't still have access to the messages state